# HTML folder path: Linking from one folder to another

Tags: html, hyperlink, path

I'm having a serious issue linking from a page in one folder to another page in a different folder.

Here is the relevant structure.

The link is on navbar.php:

```
Project Folder
-includes/navbar.php
-savings/food.php
```

Here is the code for the link:

```
<a href="../savings/food.php">Food</a>
```

I thought that this syntax would point to the right place. '../' bringing it back one level to the main folder and then '/savings/food.php' pointing to the right folder and page.

I'd be very grateful to anyone that can help me figure this out.

Folder Structure:

```
Project Folder
-includes/overall/top.php
```

This is where the navbar is included and top.php is included into the other pages

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your link, where does it take you now?

Comment: Keep in mind that I'm currently working on localhost. The link brings up a bunch of php errors. "Warning: include(includes/metadata.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Projects\Pauper\savings\food.php on line 5"

Comment: Are you including the navbar.php in a file in another directory?  If that is the case, the link path needs to based on the file it is included in.

Comment: Ok, the navbar.php page is included on a file that makes up the top part of the page. That file is then included on every new page.

Comment: So how does the directory structure look with respect to the files it is included in?. Can you draw it like your initial picture for me?

Comment: Added the folder structure in the main post

Comment: so, since it is one directory deeper then the navbar, it would be, ../../food.php.